# How can I build Flutter web with Skia

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, renderer, skia

I want to improve the performance of my Flutter site.
For running locally I use this command:
`flutter run -d chrome --dart-define=FLUTTER_WEB_USE_SKIA=true` and it works nice,
but I cannot find info on how to keep this performance in release builds.
`flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit` - does not give so much. So, how to use Skia in release builds for deployment. Thanks!

Comment: Hope you are on the latest stable version. If so check out this (https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/platform-views-using-html-slots-web#summary)
Flutter now renders all web platform views in a consistent location of the DOM, as direct children of flt-glass-pane (regardless of the rendering backend: html or canvaskit).

Comment: @AravinthanSubramanian so, Skia works only on local?